# AWS iOS SDK upload videos and access compressed files from Cloud Front

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, compression, amazon-cloudfront

My app:

- records videos and uploads them on **Amazon** (with a **CloudFront** distribution)
- plays these videos (in a `AVPlayer`) by downloading them from **CloudFront**

I use the AWS iOS SDK. I'd like to reduce the latency when playing files (especially long with a medium internet connection).

I tried 2 things:

**1) CloudFront compression**

- I set `Compress Objects Automatically` to `YES` on my CloudFront distribution configuration and upload my video normally but I'm not even sure Cloud Front compresses video files ([File types that CF compresses](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html#compressed-content-cloudfront-file-types))
- I'm supposed to set `Accept-Encoding: gzip` somewhere when downloading the video but I don't see where... I usually use `AWSS3TransferUtility` with a default configuration

**2) Client side compression**

- I compress the video myself with the [GzipSwit](https://github.com/1024jp/GzipSwift) library and upload it to Amazon. I should run some more tests to be sure but the compression is not always very effective, sometimes it doesn't change the size of the file.
- I download the data from the CloudFront url, unzip it, save it locally, play it. Here, do I need to set `Accept-Encoding: gzip` too?

I'm open to both solutions (since both are supposed to reduce the latency) but right now I can't make any of them work.

Thanks in advance for all the advice I can get.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

Accept-Encoding comes from the incoming client request. The client which makes the call to the URL must send that header.

If you are using S3 and you need to do one more step, with S3 CORS configuration.

https://ithoughthecamewithyou.com/post/enable-gzip-compression-for-amazon-s3-hosted-website-in-cloudfront

**Option 2:**

You can compress and host it in S3. The client request does not need Accept-Encoding header. Since it can download the file as it is.

**Conclusion:**

Option 1 is better since you might compress with the best compression, but the client can request with multiple options. Eg.,

Accept-Encoding: br;q=1.0, gzip;q=0.8, *;q=0.1

It this option it says to use compression with br or gzip and the compression factor as well.

Leave the file as it is in S3 and leave the compression to CloudFront. Based on the client parameters it can respond with the encoding standards.

Also if there is any method of new compression introduced, it will work by default and let the CF decide what to do with that.

More info on encoding,

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding

Comment: Problems: [CloudFront only compresses text-based content](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html#compressed-content-cloudfront-file-types), and only with gzip, not Brotli (`br`). Gzip is not a useful compression algorithm for video files, as they already tend to have minimal redundancy so the resulting file will still tend to be very close to the size of the original.  A gzip compressed file of a video file (or any already-compressed content) can sometimes turn out to be larger than the original.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Do you have any idea of what compression algorithm to use for videos?

Comment: And thanks @Michael-sqlbot for confirming me that I can't compress videos with CloudFront.

Comment: @MarieDm video (and audio) do not lend themselves well to the same kinds of reversible, lossless compression that text and documents do.  Example, MP3 audio is smaller than PCM because information is actually discarded by an algorithm that tries (imperfectly) to determine what's relevant to the ear, so it's not compression (reversible), it's data reduction.  The same general principle holds for video codecs.  Making a file meaningfully smaller generally requires different encoding parameters and a loss of quality.  Finding the balance of quality/size is a bit like finding the holy grail.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for letting know about the binary compression not possible with cloudfront.